# Store foreach loop values in a variable in PHP

Tags: php

I have a `foreach loop` in php. I want to store the output values of this loop in a variable. How can I do it? I want to store the given loop values in $my_variable

```
$my_variable = foreach( $orders as $order ){
    echo get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_tracking_box', true ).', ';
}
```

$my_variable should give direct values not the array

Comment: Push the values onto an array instead of echoing them.

Comment: `foreach` doesn't have a value, assigning it to a variable doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have tried this also but it is also not working, `$variable = function(){ 
foreach($orders as $order){echo get_post_meta($order->get_id(), '_tracking_box', true).', ';}
};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the values to an array. Then use `implode()` to concatenate them into a string with `,` separators.

```
$tracking_array = [];
foreach( $orders as $order ){
    $tracking_array[] = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_tracking_box', true );
}
$tracking_box = implode(', ', $tracking_array);
```

Comment: Sir, I have tried this but wordpress giving an error `There has been a critical error on this website`

Comment: I had a typo, a missing `;` on the first line.